# display widgets on map view

Tags: android, view, dictionary, widget

i am new developer in android application.i would like to display Google map in my application.here i would like to display android widgets on map view.can i display android widgets like Buttons,Edit text boxes,Text views et.,

i have design code for get the map in xml as follows

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
             android:id="@+id/mapId" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:enabled="true"
             android:clickable="true"
             android:apiKey="XYX_API_CODE_HERE_XYX"
             />
```

please any body can help me

Thanks in adavnce

Comment: I highly recomend you removing your API key from the example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are beautifull demos shipped with the android SDK:

> If you'd like to look at sample code, the Google APIs add-on includes an example application called MapsDemo that you can load into your development environment and run. The application is located in the Google APIs directory:
> /add-ons/google_apis-API_LEVEL/samples/MapsDemo

Edit:

I missread your question in the first place. What you want to do could best be done with a `FrameLayout`. I.E.:

```
<FrameLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
         android:id="@+id/mapId" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:enabled="true"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:apiKey="XYX_API_CODE_HERE_XYX"
         />
     <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
           <!-- Your other widgets (buttons, inputBoxes, etc) goes here -->
     </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: If my answer was the correct one, it's common to click the accept-button left to it (the grey tick). So this question gets marked as solved and I get some credits for it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a FrameLayout, you can add different views in the same space.
In your layout xml file, write a FrameLayout with its children as MapView along with buttons, textview, etc.

You can organize the views using layout_gravity as left, right, center, center_horizontal, cener_vertical, etc.

Comment: hey varuaa i would like display map as background on map i want display edit text or radio buttons or buttons etc.,